# Visual Studio no interpreta un clase que 'hereda' de Form como tal

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Por lo que entiendo, un formulario sólo puede heredar de `Form`, no puede tener múltiples herencias. Es decir, no podría hacerse lo siguiente:

```
public partial class frmCliente : Form,  BaseMaestro<Cliente>
```

No obstante, si hago lo siguiente:

```
public abstract class BaseMaestro<T> : Form
```

Y además `frmCliente` es otra clase que, a su vez, hereda de la anterior:

```
public partial class frmCliente : BaseMaestro<Cliente>
```

De manera que `frmCliente` estaría heredando de `Form`.

Sin embargo, VS no lo interpreta ya como tal y no puedo añadirle controles utilizando el diseñador. ¿Hay alguna manera de solucionar este pequeño inconveniente?

No se puede mostrar el diseñador para este archivo porque ninguna de las clases que contiene se pueden diseñar. El diseñador inspeccionó las siguientes clases en el archivo:

```
frmCliente --- La clase base `Example.WindowsForms.Clases.BaseMaestro<Example.EntidadesDominio.Cliente>`
```

no se pudo cargar. Asegúrese de que se ha hecho referencia al ensamblado y que se generaron todos los proyectos.

Me sale este error 
[image: NO dibuja el formulario]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es válido extender la clase Form pero el diseñador de Visual Studio requiere que la base sea una clase instanciable.

En tu código `BaseMaestro<T>` es una clase abstracta, lo que significa que no puede ser instanciada. Esto sólo afecta el editor gráfico de VS por como trabaja internamente, así que podrías programar tu clase en el editor de código y compilaría, pero no creo que sea lo que buscas.

Una forma de evitar este problema es definir una clase que herede de la abstracta antes:

```
public class Maestro<T>: BaseMaestro<T>
```

Y usar esa clase en tu forma:

```
public partial class frmCliente : Maestro<Cliente>
```

Pero con esto tienes que declarar todo en la nueva clase y pierdes la ventaja de usar una clase abstracta.

Si la definiste para tener código en común, podrías simplemente heredar de una clase normal, sin hacerla abstracta.

```
public class BaseMaestro<T> : Form
```

Como mencionas usar múltiples herencias, dependiendo de lo que necesites podría ser que te convenga mejor usar interfases. Una clase puede implementar más de una interfaz, en tu caso podrías hacer:

```
public partial class frmCliente : Form, InterfazForma1<Cliente>, InterfazForma2<Cliente>
```

O incluso una mezcla de ambas soluciones:

```
public partial class frmCliente : BaseMaestro<Cliente>, InterfazForma<Cliente>
```

Herendando las funciones comunes de BaseMaestro y cumpliendo con lo específico de cada forma de acuerdo a lo definido en la interfaz.

Aquí hay más información sobre cuando elegir una o la otra:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scsyfw1d(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Hola, lo que nececito hacer es pasarle un objeto entidad como por ejemplo: Cliente, Proveedor, etc a una clase BaseMaestro, que dentro de ella habran metodos como Save, New, Delete... por eso necesito pasarle el objeto de entidad a BaseMaestro

Comment: Markoan, hice lo que me recomendastes de la Clase Maestro<T> : BaseMaestro<T> igual me sale el mismo error, edite la pregunta he puesto la imagen del error.

Comment: De esta manera me esta dando problemas, le pasare la entidad cuando llamae al formulario.

Comment: El ejemplo lo probé y si funciona. Me parece que lo único que falta es que compiles el proyecto. Cierra la ventana del editor de la forma y compila tu código para que el editor encuentre la referencia de tus clases.

Comment: @PedroÁvila ¿Te sirvió la solución? Espero puedas aceptar la respuesta so te ayudó.

Comment: Si me sirvio la respuesta gracias!!!

Comment: @markoan, eres el put0 amo, compilé el proyecto volví a intentar abrir y si funcionó.  Musha gracia.